# Can I store multiple cars in 1 garage?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm not sure about this. I did it and both cars stayed in the same garage (checked a short time after). But will this be permanent or will one car be removed if I stay to long away or something similar?

Comment: I remember doing this in GTA 3. Got 5 cars into a 2 car garage by putting some on top of the others. Then they blew up.

Comment: @Studoku: Haha :D I played this game for months, but can't remember such thing. I bought a second hand graphics card back then just for this game with my little pocket money. Aaah, the memories... :) I always used the fly cheat and rotated the tank-gun to fire backwards. Incredible speed + flying over the map.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can indeed store multiple in one garage, if you squeeze them in. So long as they fit, they will save.

Edit: To edit my post to best answer the OP, they will save and the cars will stay there until you go back to the garage and remove one yourself.

Edit 2: More information on GTA V garages.

Each character has a purchasable 4 car garage, in these you can only store 4 cars.

You can store 2 cars in Michael's safehouse garage, 2 at Franklin's Safehouse garage, and 1 at each of Trevor's safehouse garages.

This leaves you with a grand total of 18 cars you can store in Story Mode. 50 for gta online, however.

Edit 3: More information on GTA Online Garages

> As of the 'executive and criminals dlc' in gta online you can total buildings/apartments with garages that hold between 2-10 cars. You can buy 5 parking garages/high-end apartments (which have 10 car garages) for a total of 30 saved cars.

Thanks [VanBuzzKill](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/37612/vanbuzzkill) for the GTA Online information

Comment: Is there no restriction in number? I remember, in GTA:SA you could store four vehicles (after two, you had to get out of the vehicle in front of the garage, get back in and drive in quickly) without anyone being removed. If you added a fifth (bikes fit easily) it would simply remove the first vehicle you added after visiting the garage again. So what is the maximum number of cars in a GTA V garage?

Comment: Edited my answer to answer your question

Comment: As for Online you can own up to 3 total buildings/apartments with garages that hold between 2-10 cars. You can buy 3 parking garages/high-end apartments (which have 10 car garages) for a total of 30 saved cars.

Comment: Edited answer with your comment and credited you, thanks for the info @VanBuzzKill